# How to assign value to text property of TaxonomyWebTaggingControl?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy picker control which is multi-allow type. I want to populate the text of that control.

My code is:

```
BindTaxonomyControls();
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList pagesLibrary = ListHelper.GetListByUrl(currentWeb.Lists, ListNames.Pages);
if (pagesLibrary != null)
{                
    SPListItem currentPage = pagesLibrary.GetItemById(id);
    txtNewsTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPage[FieldNames.Title]);
    if (currentPage[FieldNames.Offices] != null)
    {   
        TaxonomyFieldValueCollection officesValue = currentPage[FieldNames.Offices] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;

        if (officesValue != null)
        {
            foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue office in officesValue)
            {

                string.Concat(twtcOffices.Text, string.Format("{0}|{1}", Convert.ToString(office), Convert.ToString(office.TermGuid)));
            }
        }
    }
}
private void BindTaxonomyControls()
{
    try
    {
        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        TaxonomyField officeField = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Offices) as TaxonomyField;
        if (officeField != null)
        {
            twtcControl.TermSetId.Add(officeField.TermSetId);
            twtcControl.SspId.Add(officeField.SspId);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    finally
    { }
}
```

I referred [this](http://santhoshsharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/08/using-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.html) post to assign the multiple values to the `taxonomywebtaggingcontrol` but I am not getting the field populated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to specify TaxonomyWebTaggingControl value (see [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.text%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Property):

> Set values into this control as pairs of labels and GUIDs. The
>   delimiter between a label and a GUID is the | character. When using
>   multiple values, delimit them with a ; character. Example:
>   term1|12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012;term2|87654321-4321-4321-4321-210987654321

In your case:

```
twtcOffices.Text = string.Concat(twtcOffices.Text, string.Format("{0}|{1}", Convert.ToString(office), Convert.ToString(office.TermGuid)));
```

---